# MVVM VisualBrush Binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, mahapps.metro

Dont know if this is the "best" way to do it.
I'm learning the concept of MVVM, sorry about that.

I have 4 Buttons and i want to show a VisualBrush inside a Rectangle.
Here is my Code:

View:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands Name="WindowCommand" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.WindowCommandItems}">
        <Controls:WindowCommands.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ModelType:MainModel}">
                <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20">
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Icon}" />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="{Binding Header}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Controls:WindowCommands.ItemTemplate>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

ViewModel:

```
private void CreateWindowCommands() {
        var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        myResourceDictionary.Source =
            new Uri("/BlackBoxBot;component/Resources/Icons.xaml",
                    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        Model.WindowCommandItems = new ObservableCollection<Models.MainModel.WindowCommandModel> {
            new Models.MainModel.WindowCommandModel {
                Header = "Viewer",
                Icon = new VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)myResourceDictionary["users"] as Canvas}
            },
            new Models.MainModel.WindowCommandModel {
                Header = "Home",
                Icon = new VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)myResourceDictionary["appbar_home"] as Canvas }
            },
            new Models.MainModel.WindowCommandModel {
                Header = "Dashboard",
                Icon = new VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)myResourceDictionary["theater"] as Canvas }
            },
            new Models.MainModel.WindowCommandModel {
                Header = "Einstellungen",
                Icon = new VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)myResourceDictionary["settings"] as Canvas }
            }
        };
     ......
```

Model:

```
[PropertyChanged.ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class WindowCommandModel {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public ICommand Command { get; set; } = new RoutedCommand();
        public VisualBrush Icon { get; set; }
    }
```

My result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J62Us.png)

Why is my icon not displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Icon}" />
```

[VisualBrush.Visual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.visual(v=vs.110).aspx) expects the object to be of type `Visual`

You are binding to a `VisualBrush`.

```
Icon = new VisualBrush() { Visual = (Visual)myResourceDictionary["users"] as Canvas}
```

Try this instead:

```
Icon = myResourceDictionary["users"] as Canvas
```